# Codeigniter update specific value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in MySql Database that has **post_id , post_number , post_like**

I am using MVC in codeigniter to fetch all the data from the mysql table and display it on a page (this part is done)

I need to add a button for each **post_id** that adds +1 to the **post_like** in the mysql table, that corresponds to the post_id.

So if I click the +1 button for post_id 7, the post_like should only increase for post_id 7.

Here is what I have so far!

**view_page.php**

```
     <?php foreach($members as $value): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $value['post_id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['post_like']; ?></td>
          <td> <a href="plusone/<?php echo $value['post_id']; ?>">Add +1</a></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**controller_page.php**

```
   <?php


    function plusone($post_id){

       $this->load->model('model_page');
       $this->model_page->data_addition($post_id);
       redirect('controller_page/viewdata');

   }

   ?>
```

**Model_page.php**

```
        <?php

    function data_addition($post_id){

       //trying to add 1 the post_like and update it in the db
        $add_one_to_data = $post_like+ 1;

        $data = array(
           'post_like' => $add_one_to_data +1 
        );

        $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->update('post_tbl', $data); 

    }

   ?>
```

Please don't laugh at the **$add_one_to_data** I added above the array, I didnt know what else to do

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the ifno first like:

```
function data_addition($post_id){
       $post_like = $this->db->get_where('post_tbl', array('post_id' => $post_id))->row();

       //trying to add 1 the post_like and update it in the db
        $add_one_to_data = (int) $post_like->post_like + 1;

        $data = array(
           'post_like' => $add_one_to_data +1 
        );

        $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
        $this->db->update('post_tbl', $data); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your `data_addition` function with this

```
function data_addition($post_id){  
    $this->db->set('post_like', 'post_like+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
    $this->db->update('post_tbl');
}
```